# Getting the Letters After The Second To Last slash in a URL

Tags: java

I have a url that I'm trying to get the letters that are after the second to last `/`

Trying to get `12345`

`String url = "https://imgur.com/a/12345/all";`

I am struggling to figure out how to create an algorithm for my dynamic function:

```
private static String getNthCharacters(String url, int position){
        if(position == 1){
            return url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        }
        
        return null;
    }
```

```
Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: " + getNthCharacters(url, 1));
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by a "better" way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what I think you're asking for.  It lets you say "the second to last" by giving the function a negative position:

```
public class Test {

    private static String getNthCharacters(String url, int position) {
        String[] parts = url.split("/");
        if (position < 0)
            position = parts.length + position;
        return parts[position];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "https://imgur.com/a/12345/all";
        String r = getNthCharacters(url, -2);
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
12345
```